# How should I implement a dynamic partner link endpoint in WSO2 BPS?

Tags: wso2, bpel, wso2-business-process

I am trying to implement a partner link with a dynamically determined endpoint address in a WSO2 BPS BPEL process. The idea is that the request sent to the process contains an endpoint URL and that this URL is used as the address for a certain partner link. I have successfully used endpoint references stored in the registry before, but I can't use that approach here as the address can be different every time the process is called.

I have tried a number of different approaches (using WSO2 BPS 3.5.1 and WS02 Developer Studio 3.8.0):

- The approach used in the DynPartner example referenced in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092515/dynamic-partner-links-and-dynamic-addressing-with-ode-bpel. This gives me the following validation error in Developer Studio: `The from-spec of "<xs:simpleType "string">" is not compatible with to-spec of "<wsdl:portType 
  "DynResponderPortType">"`. Also, when I deploy and invoke the process, I get an error stating that the endpoint cannot be created (`Couldnt create any endpoint for element ...`)
- Assigning a fixed value to the partner link, e.g. like this:

  ```
  <wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsdl11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com uep_schema.xsd">
     <wsa:Address>http://localhost:8281/services/serviceaddress</wsa:Address>
  </wsa:EndpointReference>
  ```

  This works and does not give a validation error, but I haven't found a way to dynamically change the address that is used here based on the input my process is called with.
- Create a variable that holds the endpoint reference, using a type that defines the content of an endpoint reference. I've tried several XSDs (http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/OS/serviceref/ws-bpel_serviceref.xsd, http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/components/unified-endpoint/org.wso2.carbon.unifiedendpoint.core/4.2.0/src/main/resources/schema/uep_schema.xsd (which doesn't get validated without errors), the ws-addr.xsd from w3c, my own very simple XSD). I've had varying success with regarding how well Developer Studio could handle them and for instance generate initializations, but they all share the problem that I get a validation error stating something like `The from-spec of "<element "EndpointReference">" is not compatible with to-spec of "<wsdl:portType 
  "ThisIsThePartnerLinkPortType">" -`.

At this point, I am using the last approach with my own simple XSD. The process is actually working the way I intend it to, but I am still getting validation errors in Developer Studio which I would like to get rid of. Is there another and better way to approach this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is having the same issue: The approach is use now is that the BPS calls a specific proxy in the ESB (at a fixed location) and provides the endpoint URL to that proxy. The proxy then performs the actual call to the endpoint.

This has a number of advantages for me:

- I get rid of the validation errors in the BPEL designer
- Passing through the ESB allows me to perform validation on the message that I receive from the service located at the dynamic URL. Note that this is not possible in the BPS at the moment, as validation is not yet properly implemented. See also https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS351/WS-BPEL+2.0+Specification+Compliance